# codeigner is not loading css file on 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

hi i have spent whole day by searching over internet that codeigniter is not loading the css and js files I modified the htaccess rule to enable clean urls here is code sample
RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

the project is on my computer
can you please tell me how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

you can use this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

also be sure you putted all your css and js files out of the `/application` dir

usually:

```
/root
  /application
  /system
  /css
  /js
```

then be sure your config/config.php has:

```
 $config['base_url']    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

and you easly load css like this:

```
<link src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/file.css" ?> />
```

Comment: this is not working either.only home page is working and if i open another page , it takes me to wamp home page

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas which is your directory structure ? please post it , and post your config.php file too ;)

Comment: the whole project is in  http://127.0.0.1/tools/

the config file is 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Answer (score 0):

This Is My htaccess this is working for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sampleappbase/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

In the Views-->

```
"<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.css" />"
"<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to put all CSS, JS and img files in a separate folder that's outside of the application folder. I put them all in a folder that's called "public" Then use

```
//Define the base URL
$base_url = $this->config->base_url();
```

And in the HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>public/css/style.css"/>
<script src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>public/js/js_file.js"></script>
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

IF this is not work please check your Xampp or Wamp